# map is not refreshing using gmaps4jsf

Tags: gmaps4jsf

I am using gmaps4jsf jar file for getting dynamic marker on google map but once i click on submit button then getting whole data on web page, evem map also with dynamic marker but map marker is coming after refresh the page.

**jsf code**:

```
<m:map id="map" width="650px" height="450px" latitude="#{map.latitude}" longitude="#{map.longitude}" enableScrollWheelZoom="true" zoom="9">                   
    <m:marker latitude="#{point.latitude}" longitude="#{point.longitude}" >
       <m:htmlInformationWindow htmlText="Click me!" />
    </m:marker>                    
</m:map>

<p:column>
  <p:commandButton value="Display" action="#{map.display}" update="form"/>
</p:column>
```

jsf component is refreshing fine only problem with google map..

Comment: What are you using for refresh the map?

Comment: I don't have any idea how to refresh map because i am using first time gmaps4jsf and my jsf component is working properly

Comment: you should use partial trigger in map tag. it will work.

Comment: How? can you send me example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should use **partiallyTriggered="true"** for refresh the google map. as you said you are using gmaps4jsf jar so it will help and i'm updating your code so you can find here

```
<m:map id="map" partiallyTriggered="true" width="650px" height="450px" latitude="#{map.latitude}" longitude="#{map.longitude}" enableScrollWheelZoom="true" zoom="9">                   
    <m:marker latitude="#{point.latitude}" longitude="#{point.longitude}" >
       <m:htmlInformationWindow htmlText="Click me!" />
    </m:marker>                    
</m:map>
```

Comment: Great it's working, Thanks can you tell me how to provide link for htmlInformationWindow?

Comment: new question in question. first do google if you don't find then ask the question :)